# vector copy does not work, but manual push_back does

Tags: c++, stl

I have a weird behavior, and this is probably a beginner's question:

In a class member function I am trying to replace a given vector by another vector.

```
template <typename FITNESS_TYPE>
void BaseManager<FITNESS_TYPE>::replacePopulation (
typename Population<FITNESS_TYPE>::chromosome_container replacementPopulation)
{
    _population.getChromosomes().clear();

   //This inserts the contents of replacementPopulation into _population.getChromosomes()
    for (
          typename Population<FITNESS_TYPE>::chromosome_container::iterator 
          it  = replacementPopulation.begin();
          it != replacementPopulation.end();
          ++it)
          {
             _population.getChromosomes().push_back(*it);
          }


    //But this does nothing...
     std::copy(replacementPopulation.begin(),replacementPopulation.end(), _population.getChromosomes().begin());


     for (typename Population<FITNESS_TYPE>::chromosome_container::iterator it = _population.getChromosomes().begin(); it!=_population.getChromosomes().end(); ++it)
     {
         std::cout << "CHROM: " << **it << std::endl;
     }
}
```

The corresponding getChromosomes() getter are as follows:

```
template <typename FITNESS_TYPE>
class Population : public printable {
public:
    typedef typename std::vector<Chromosome::BaseChromosome<FITNESS_TYPE>* > chromosome_container;
    typedef typename chromosome_container::const_iterator const_it;
    typedef typename chromosome_container::iterator it;
    const chromosome_container& getChromosomes() const { return _chromosomes; }
    chromosome_container& getChromosomes() { return _chromosomes; }
private:
    chromosome_container _chromosomes;
};
```

Im confused. Why does the copy not work like the for loop?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that the two parts of the first function have been tested separately? (i.e. they don't normally appear together)

Comment: yes, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`push_back` resizes the vector, whereas writing to `begin()` and what comes after it assumes that the space is already there. What you want looks like this:

```
std::copy(replacementPopulation.begin(),
          replacementPopulation.end  (),
          std::back_inserter(_population.getChromosomes()));
```

`#include <iterator>` to get `back_inserter`.

In essence, `std::back_inserter` is an iterator that does a `push_back` every time something is written to it.

Answer (score 4):

`copy` requires that its output iterator be the start of a valid range at least as large as the input range. In your case, it's the start of an empty range; so `copy` will increment it off the end of the vector, writing into whatever memory lies beyond, and causing undefined behaviour.

The simplest solution here is just to reassign the vector

```
_population.getChromosomes() = replacementPopulation;
```

If you did need to append to a vector, rather than replace all its contents, you could use an insertion iterator:

```
std::copy(replacementPopulation.begin(), replacementPopulation.end(),
          std::back_inserter(_population.getChromosomes()));
```

Answer (score 3):

`vector` actually has an `insert` method that takes iterators:

```
_population.getChromosomes().insert(
    _population.getChromosomes().end(),
    replacementPopulation.begin(),
    replacementPopulation.end());
```

That'll make sure that `_population.getChromosomes()` is resized correctly so you can't run off the end. Also will only do one `reserve()` if necessary based on the distance between the two iterators, so this will be strictly more efficient than the `std::copy()` solutions proposed.

Alternatively, if you're literally just copying the vector:

```
_population.getChromosomes() = replacementPopulation;
```

Comment: thanks for the tip. btw is there a way to clear the vector without resizing the capacity?

Comment: @mightyuhu: [`std::vector::clear()` doesn't change the capacity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear).

Answer (score 1):

Copy assumes that there is space for copied elements in destination container, and it will replace them. You can use "back_inserter" to create an special iterator that will insert elements instead of replacing to avoid the need for resizing before the copy.

```
std::copy(replacementPopulation.begin(),replacementPopulation.end(), std::back_inserter(_population.getChromosomes()));
```